# How to script an application using AppleScript, but only if installed?

Tags: applescript

A few of my scripts notify using Growl, but I'm trying to run them now on a machine that doesn't have Growl installed.

This line

```
tell application "Growl"
    notify with name "Script" title "Script" description NotifyText application name "Script" with sticky
--                   _
end tell
```

Gives this compiler error at the character underlined:

> Expected “given”, “into”, “with”, “without”, other parameter name, etc. but found “"”.

How can an AppleScript optionally use an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge **Script Editor** does not have a *conditional compile directive* and if an application is not installed then it will error out on compile. In some cases, **Script Editor** can be faked out into compiling by creating a dummy app in the name of the missing application but this has limited application and success and really depends on the *code* written for the missing application.

As to writing *code* to conditionally use a target application if it's installed, one needs to test for its existence and wrap the target applications *code* in a `if` *statement block*. In the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, I have a test video file in my **Movies** folder that I want to play in **VLC** if it's installed, and if not then play in **QuickTime Player**, e.g.:

```
set thisVideo to (path to movies folder as string) & "test.mp4"

try
    tell application "Finder" to get application file id "org.videolan.vlc"
    set appExists to true
on error
    set appExists to false
end try

if appExists then
    set theApp to "VLC"
    tell application theApp to open thisVideo
else
    tell application "QuickTime Player"
        open thisVideo
        play document 1
    end tell
end if
```

Now I do not have **Growl** installed but the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown above should work for it as well. From a Mac that has it installed, you just need to ascertain its `bundle identifier` *property* while the target application is running and use it in place of what's in the *example code*, i.e.:

```
tell application "System Events" to get bundle identifier of application process "Growl"
```

---

**Note:** The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not employ any other *error handling* then what's shown and is meant only to show one of many ways to accomplish a task. The onus is always upon the User to add/use appropriate *error handling* as needed/wanted.

Comment: One point to note is that, while this will prevent an error being thrown if, say, *VLC* is not installed, *Script Editor* will open a dialog box in order to be shown where the application file for *VLC* is to be found.  It does this when trying to compile the script, and during execution.  Perhaps there's a way to circumvent this.

Comment: @CJK, When originally testing, yes the Choose Application dialog box did appear, however clicking the Cancel button allowed it to compile and or run the `else` _branch_ of the `if` _statement_. That said, I've updated the _code_ so the Choose Application dialog box doesn't come into play. Thanks for bringing up the point!

Comment: CJK, Thanks, but that might be premature, while it works in the example use case, it does not work with Growl unless you first compile it on a system that has Growl installed and save the script.  It actually should be saved as an application so it stays compiled. I guess I'm going to have to buy Growl and give it a try. I'll update it this weekend.